# Moving background stops repeating on Spritekit

Tags: ios, background, sprite-kit

This is my code to make my background repeat, just one background and it should be repeating forever:

```
SKTexture* bgTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"nightbackground"];
bgTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKAction* movebgSprite = [SKAction moveByX:-bgTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0.1 * bgTexture.size.width*2];
SKAction* resetbgSprite = [SKAction moveByX:bgTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0];
SKAction* movebgSpritesForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[movebgSprite, resetbgSprite]]];

for( int i = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width / ( bgTexture.size.width * 2 ); ++i ) {
    SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:bgTexture];
    [sprite setScale:1.0];
    sprite.zPosition = -20;
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    [sprite runAction:movebgSpritesForever];
    [self addChild:sprite];
```

But it does not repeat forever, it stops after a while. What might be wrong with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sprite Kit: parallax background does not repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969989/sprite-kit-parallax-background-does-not-repeat)

Comment: please don't repost the same question, edit your original question if you need to make any changes to it

Comment: please reply on their

Answer (score 1):

This case will work in landscape orientation and have the view repeat scrolling infinitely to the left (-x direction).  You create two instances of the background SKSPriteNode and place them next to each other.  When the first one scrolls completely off the left side of the screen, it is placed to the right of the second background sprite node.

in didMoveToView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    bg.position = CGPointMake(i * bg.size.width, 0);
    bg.name = @"starBackground";
    [self addChild:bg];
}
```

in the update: loop

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"background" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    SKSpriteNode *bg = (SKSpriteNode *)node;
    bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x - 1.5, bg.position.y);

    if (bg.position.x <= -bg.size.width) {
        bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x + bg.size.width * 2, bg.position.y);
    }

}];
```